# I need to change the attribute of the isPermaLink guid in the Wordpress RSS feed - from false to true

Tags: permalinks, rss, feed, guids

I need to change the attribute of the isPermaLink guid in the Wordpress RSS feed - from false to true.

```
<guid isPermaLink="false"></guid>
```

What's the best way to do this without having to change the code every time the theme is updated?

Comment: Succinctly, apply your change in a dedicated plugin instead of modifying a theme. But why would you want to change that attribute? GUIDs generally should not be used as a URL even if they are set as a URL.  If you change your permalink settings or migrate your posts to a different installation, the GUID would become an incorrect URL reference to the content. You might think to change all the GUIDs to match the new site/path/permalink - but changing the core identifier for content would have an undesirable impact on how the rest of the web interprets the site's content.

Comment: See [this note in the DevHub](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#important-guid-note) for a little more context.